# Monitoring distance between two locations

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services

I m monitoring the distance between **many devices approching a single device** using Map, when it reaches certain distance i want to trigger a **notifcation**. What database i need to use for fastest triggering. Did web service enough? It need to be sending requests frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sockets for that because they are real time ,as you need to get their current location in every second whether they reach a particular destination or not.use pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'  and implement them in your application and also  on your server end.

Comment: Look like the pod u have mensioned is only for swift. Is it?

Comment: No you can also use this for objective c ,I also made a chat application using the same one in objective c

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate what did mean by server end. How i can create it.

Comment: Server end means you also have to implement socket on the server end.

Comment: In my case might be have requirement to act same device as server and client. was it really possible?

Comment: No its not possible to act a same device as a server or client at same time.